# [RAILS]image_tag not showing only with good path

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image

I'm having an image_tag that is supposed to display... an image. The problem is that if I set the src of the image to something that doesn't existe, it appear on the page (the broken link icon) but if I set the correct path to the image, nothing is displayed, even in the page source code... here is the code I'm using :

```
<% if @event.banner %>                                  
  <%= image_tag "/banners/" + @event.banner.path %>
<% end %>
```

I tried to put the relative path (like here), the absolute path with 'http://mywebsite.com/banners/y.jpg'.
The image is located in the public folder. It is reachable through the url I wrote above.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : I tried with image_tag and `<img />` tag

Comment: `<%= image_tag "/banners/#{@event.banner.path}" %>` is correct Rails code

Comment: Yes, right but event with #{}, that's not changing anything

Comment: Can you give us the rendered HTML for your `image` tag?

Comment: The problem is that there is no render, absolutly nothing. With a bad path there is the <img> tag but with the good path, the <img> tag is inexistant. :(

Comment: Can you try this `<%= "/banners/#{@event.banner.path}" %>` & let us know the result?

Comment: It's displaying the path of my image `/banners/3.jpg`

Comment: Can you try image_tag("/banners/#{@event.banner.path}") again? Also there is the problem that the src of am image tag is looking under assets not public

Comment: Still nothing. I already used image_tag with images in the public folders in the website and there is no problem with those.
I even tried to put the full link and it's giving the same result

Comment: The problem is likely to do with your storing of images in the `public` folder -- have you tried storing in `assets/images` to see if that loads?

Comment: I already displayed image from this public folder without problem. I store those images here because it's uploaded from the users and I had problem storing it in assets/images. Even if there would be a problem, I should get the broken link icon and not "nothing" right ?

Comment: The html image tag is appearing when the page is loading but it disappear as soon as the loading ends...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no idea of why I'm having this problem but it's not acting like this on another browser.